# Is it worth upgrading my jailbroken 3G to iOS4?

Tags: jailbreak, ios, iphone

I have a jailbroken (not unlocked) iPhone 3G running the 3.1.2 firmware. What are the pros and cons of upgrading this to iOS4?

Being jailbroken, I already have multitasking and home-screen wallpapers. What does the new iOS give me that I don't already have access to?

Answer (score 5):

I've done it and it's not worth the trouble.  I'm considering rolling back to 3.1.2.

The beneficial changes are minimal (and most can be provided by a jailbreak app), and the performance decrease is very noticeable.  I've found that crashes are much more frequent as well.

My advice: Don't do it.

Comment: 3.2 is iPad only. 3.1.3 is the previous iPhone version :-)

Comment: Ahh, I think I meant 3.1.2 (changed)

Comment: +1. I upgraded to 4.0 and experienced how painfully slow it was. I've downgraded again and I'm happy. I have no need at all for the new features -- folders, single mailbox, etc. -- that's all just bloat to me. I'm sure v4.x is great on faster devices though.

Answer (score 4):

In my personal experience, iOS 4 was only marginally slower than iPhone OS 3, so it really comes down to features.

First, iOS 4 does *not* allow you to put home screen wallpapers on an iPhone 3G. I don't have experience with multitasking on a jailbroken device, but again iOS does not provide this functionality on the iPhone 3G. However, given the memory and processor of the iPhone 3G, you really wouldn't *want* to multitask on the device.

In terms of features that iOS 4 *does* offer the iPhone 3G, [here are some top ones](http://www.apple.com/iphone/softwareupdate/):

1. **Mail** - unified inbox, multiple Exchange accounts, message threading
2. **Folders** - a very useful way to store similar apps to save space
3. **iBooks** - eBook and PDF reader (useful, though this app was somewhat slow on my 3G)

It's also worth noting that there are already apps that require iOS 4 and the number's only going to grow. Not having iOS 4 will reduce the number of apps that will run on your device.

Since I never really got a lot of utility from jailbreaking, it made the decision to upgrade pretty easy for me. However, if having a wallpaper or running apps from Cydia is important to you, you're not *really* missing out on a whole lot, at least for now.

Comment: You'll also have direct transfer of files from iTunes to the applications that have enabled it, and the choice of open files with certain applications.

I personally find the update very convenient because of the many small improvements, specially now that I have solved the speed issues I initially had.

Answer (score 2):

Most of what I've heard is that it's not worth running on the 3G as it's very sluggish.

Comment: Resetting to factory defaults and reconfiguring has solved the issue for me.